# Hyperv-V creates mystery .avhdx files and fills up disk space

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2016, vss, vhdx, avhdx

I have windows server 2016. Also i have Hyper-V role on my server. Every day in `5:36` i have error, that `disk full` and my virtual machine is stopping. In Hyper-V logs:

```
   ProviderName: Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-StorageVSP

TimeCreated                     Id LevelDisplayName Message
-----------                     -- ---------------- -------
11.03.2018 5:36:08               5 Information         Storage device 'D:\DBS82-Data.vhdx' changed recovery state. Previous state = Recoverable Error Detected, New state = Recoverable Error Detected.
11.03.2018 5:36:08               4 Information         Storage device 'D:\DBS82-Data.vhdx' received a recovery status notification. Current device state = Recoverable Error Detected, Last status = No Errors, New status = Disk Full.
11.03.2018 5:36:08               6 Information         Storage device 'D:\DBS82-Data.vhdx' received an IO failure with error = SRB_STATUS_ERROR_RECOVERY. Current device state = No Errors, New state = Recoverable Error Detected, Current status = No Errors.
```

I tried to no sleep until `5:36` to see, what is going on, because on my disk `D` i have `80 G` of free space. `DBS82-Data.vhdx` is near `100 G`. So, i tried to no sleep and i saw, that on disk `D` was created `DBS82-Data_E8D5659C--CBA3-4813-8543-F30F264A7A2F.avhdx` file that fills up disk space. Also, in a Hyper-V manager i see in status of all virtual machines status `merging`. What is that ? Where i can manage it process ? Because on hyper-v in windows server 2008, i did not saw this problem (feature).

Comment: Do you back up the virtual machines every day?

Comment: @joeqwerty no, maybe other admin was set something, but he will absent and i should find out answer, where i can see these options

Answer (score 13):

You have either enabled the [Hyper-V Checkpoints](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/manage/enable-or-disable-checkpoints-in-hyper-v) that need to be [merged](https://trevorsullivan.net/2016/07/24/merge-hyper-v-disks/) or there is an additional snapshot managing software (backup or replication) that sends the command to Hyper-V for creating checkpoints/snapshots.

I would start with investigating the systems/application logs at the mentioned time to find out the root cause of the issue.

Comment: A fun fact for future readings -- turning off Checkpoints and deleting the "Automatic Checkpoint" causes a merge operation to happen. I did that after shutting off the Windows 10 VM and things went smoothly enough. Regained about 20-30 GB of my 256 GB SSD that way! :)